# How can I define this RSC code using poly2trellis in matlab (or python)?

Tags: python, matlab, signal-processing, encoder

[RSC Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ic9wV.png)

I'm attempting to declare this RSC defined in this diagram using the poly2trellis function. After consulting the documentation for [poly2trellis](https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/poly2trellis.html?searchHighlight=poly2trellis&s_tid=srchtitle_support_results_1_poly2trellis), I initially thought the correct approach would be:

`trellis = poly2trellis(4, [15 17 13], 15);`

Because:

`G() = [1  0()/()  1()/()]`

`0() = 1 +  + ^3`
`1() = 1 +  + ^2 + ^3`
`d() = 1 + ^2 + ^3`

`1. n0(D) = 1 + D + D^3 = 1011 = 13(octal)`

`2. n1(D) = 1 + D + D^ 2 + D^3 = 1111 =  17(octal)`

`3. d(D)  = 1 + D^2 + D^3 = 1101 = 15(octal)`

However, upon further examination and practical tests, this configuration appears to be incorrect. Could anyone provide guidance or corrections on how to accurately declare an RSC code using poly2trellis?

How to correctly use the poly2trellis

Answer (score 0):

The correct definition is:

```
trellis = poly2trellis(4,[13, 15, 17],13)
```

I was using the wrong endiness to define the octal numbers.